# ffmpeg webm video won't start

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, icecast

I have a server streaming videos encoded with ffmpeg and sent to an icecast server.

Configuration was a bit tricky and I still don't get the expected result. I think there is a problem between GOP and iframe so when requesting for the video sometimes the video start correctly and sometimes we just get 2 sec of images and the it freeze.

Here is my configuration :

```
./ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i stream/stream_list.txt 2> stream/log.txt \
    -acodec libopus -b:a 64k \
    -vcodec libvpx -b:v 500K -f webm -crf 25 -framerate 30 -g 5 -keyint_min 5 -vf scale=640:360 -maxrate 5000k -bufsize 6M -content_type video/webm \
    -loop 365 \
    icecast://source:pass@website:8000/live.webm &
```

What can I do to be sure everytime a user request for the video in his browser the video start correctly ?

I played a lot with -g and -keyint_min options but without success.

Comment: Did you enlarge the queue size and burst for that mount? It's important that the keyframe is in that first burst of data.

Comment: Thanks for helping : Option thread_queue_size (set the maximum number of queued packets from the demuxer) cannot be applied to output url icecast://blabla -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.

Comment: https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#limits

Comment: I quadruple size of queue size (from 512k to 2Mo) and the burst and burst_on_connect and even it seems to be a bit better I still have the problem. How big can I put those two values ?

Comment: That depends on the actual bitrate. I wouldn't increase the queue size. 2MB is quite large. Are you sure that your encoder is fast enough? libvpx should have a "realtime" option that sacrifices quality, for delivering the data on time.

Comment: Encoding uses 50% of CPU. I remember trying the -realtime option and from what I recall it wasn't working. It has been a big mess to get a setup working ...

Comment: If it's 50%, is that a dual core machine? That would be one core at 100%.

Comment: Yes that's completely that. So I think I've my answer. Thanks